# GDPR Module fatal errors

Tags: gdpr

I have gotten the GDPR module working in all cases that I need anyway. I'm sure there are some more issues, but I haven't gotten anymore fatal errors.

I will upload a diff, and it appears the module is abandoned, but we need it and especially the Terms and Conditions for events which now works.

I'm not a full-time dev anymore and a volunteer at our organization. The only tech person, so my time is limited. I would like to give this back. I guess I can take over the module, or fork it? What is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have opened an issue on its Github repo which is a good start.  See what response you get to that - they may be ok to hand it over but otherwise you can create a fork and submit a PR.

Comment: I suspect no response.

Comment: I see it was recently moved to GitLab not GitHub - https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr